# get RealmResults in array instead of object in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, realm

I have a simple Schema

```
const MediaElementSchema = {
    primaryKey: 'id',
    name: 'MediaElement',
    properties: {
        id: 'int',
        type: 'string',
        path: 'string'
    }
}
```

When I try to get all:

```
let elements = realm.objects('MediaElement')
```

Realm returns the results in an object like below:

```
{"0": Record1, "1" : Record2, etc}
```

is there a way for realm to return an array of the elements like:

```
[Element1, Element2, etc]
```

I checked the documentation but didn't find anything relevant about the return type.

https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use plain old javascript to convert object into array.

```
let elements = {'0': 'Record1', '1' : 'Record2'};
elements = Object.keys(elements).map(key => elements[key]);

console.log(elements); // ["Record1", "Record2"]
```

Comment: I was hoping for something native to return the results in arrays but I ended up using  your method.